# Beam projector management using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to control a beam projector using an ASP.NET web application. Using this web application, I want to pass a command i.e. turn on and turn off the beam projector and auto adjust command etc. Is it possible to do? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

One way is programming a system service for the beamer and implementing the methods to control a connected device.
Then you write a class which can then be instantiated from inside an ASP.NET page to control the beamer.

If the beamer has a .NET API, you might even pull this off yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any other way to control a beam projector without using API?

Comment: yes. It comes usually in the package, it's called remote control.(scnr)

Seriously, I can't tell you a generic .NET based method of controlling an unknown device X.